# how to perform Jmeter API performance test with multiple backend systems?

Tags: jmeter, load, stress

I want to do POST API performance test with Jmeter for the end to end system.
Backend architecture is as follows,

API <-> [A system] <-API-> [B system]

The problem is when I am setting up Jmeter POST API it just generates 200 ok status for [A system] and does not care if the request is failed in further system. But I want to test the performance of the complete system and would like to know the RESPONSE OK or NG from [B system] for the POST API called from [A system].
Is there any solution to this concern?  If more details are required about the problem let me know...

Answer (score 0):

JMeter knows nothing about downstream components which are deployed behind system `A` therefore you cannot test the whole sequence.

The options are in:

1. If `system B` can be queries somehow for the status of a particular request you could use [While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) to periodically check whether `system B` has processed the request and record the cumulative time using [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller)
2. The whole integrated system always acts at the speed of its slowest component so you can conduct 2 tests:

   - JMeter to mimic system A usage by system A consumer(s)
   - JMeter to mimic system B usage by system A

   once you have the results you can compare the throughput and state which one is slower
3. It might be the [case you can collect the statuses from the system B using JMeter PerfMon](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) Plugin or [SSHMon](https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-sshmon) Listener
4. You can consider using [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) to collect metrics from systems A and B so you will have aggregate dashboard with the results.